# How can I get a HTML Page from Spring using Ember. How to request a html page?

Tags: spring, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a login.html page in Spring. I have a controller to serve this page at port 8080. How can I get this complete page using ember?

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    LoginService loginService;

    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showJoke(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("date",loginService.getDate());

        return "login";
    }
}
```

This is my ember how will i display this page?

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({

    init: function () {
        this._super(... arguments)

        let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {

            if(httpRequest.readyState==4 && httpRequest.status==200){
                console.log("ok");
            }

        }

        httpRequest.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/login",true);
        httpRequest.send();
    }

});
```

Comment: Please add additional details about what you are trying to accomplish. I'm not sure if you're attempting to show users the login page or if you want to parse some data from that page, or a third option entirely.

Comment: I am just trying to get a html page from spring and display it. Ember will make a http request and the response will be a html page. How will i display that page using ember. (I know it is a bad idea, i just want to know how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the data and set it on the controller and then display it in the template like:

**app/controllers/application.js**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import fetch from 'fetch';

export default Controller.extend({
  htmlData: null,

  init: function () {
    this._super(... arguments)
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/login').then(response => {
      this.set('htmlData', response.text());
    }); 
  }
});
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
{{this.htmlData}}
```

I used the fetch API here because I'm more familiar with it, but the action would be the same no matter how you pull in the data.